# ORACLE : How to add a nested table to an existing type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, nested-table, sql-types

I need to add a nested table to the following type that I've already created :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ELEVE_TYPE UNDER PERSONNE_TYPE (
    DATE_NAISSANCE DATE,
    POIDS NUMBER,
    ANNEE NUMBER(1),
    ADR ADRESSE_TYPE
);
/
```

Here is the table I want to add to my type :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE RESULTAT_TYPE AS OBJECT (
    NOM_COURS VARCHAR2(32),
    POINTS NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE RESULTATS_TABLE
IS TABLE OF RESULTAT_TYPE;
/
```

But the `ALTER TABLE` command I've tried to do is not working, giving the error `ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted`.
Here's my command :

```sql
ALTER TYPE ELEVE_TYPE 
ADD RESULTATS RESULTATS_TABLE NESTED TABLE RESULTATS STORE AS RESULTATS_TAB;
/
```

How do I make it work ?
Thanks in advance

EDIT : I did mean to alter a type and not a table, and my problem was solved thanks to [MT0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987272/oracle-how-to-add-a-nested-table-to-an-existing-type?noredirect=1#comment130637711_73987272) :

```sql
ALTER TYPE ELEVE_TYPE 
ADD ATTRIBUTE RESULTATS RESULTATS_TABLE CASCADE;
/
```

Comment: You typed `ALTER TYPE` and not `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: If you did mean to alter the type then do not specify how to store it as you are only defining a type and not a table; like this `ALTER TYPE ELEVE_TYPE ADD ATTRIBUTE RESULTATS RESULTATS_TABLE;` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1jMim49A)